# Why is this program not writing the final variable string to it's destination text file?

Tags: python

I'm almost there with using some Python code to pull down stock data strings passed to it from SAS to build a text file to read back into SAS, but the final output text file remains at 0 bytes, despite the code running without error and the print statements I have put in the log seeming to display valid output. Here is the code:

```
import concurrent.futures
import urllib.request
import json

with open("C:\\Python33\\NASDAQ Stock Strings\\NASDAQ_Config_File_1_a.txt", "r") as myurls:
    myurls2 = myurls.read().replace('\n', '')


URLS = [myurls2]
print('URLS =', URLS) 

# Retrieve a single page and report the url and contents
def load_url(url, timeout):
    conn = urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=timeout)
    return conn.readall()


# We can use a with statement to ensure threads are cleaned up promptly
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=50) as executor:
    # Start the load operations and mark each future with its URL
    future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_url, url, 60): url for url in URLS}

    c = 0


    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
        url = future_to_url[future]

        a = ''
        b = ''
        c += 1

        mylen = (len(myurls2)) - 1
        print('String length = %s' % (len(myurls2)))
        a = myurls2[mylen:]
        print('a=', a)


        if a == 'a':
           b =  'Ask' 
        elif a == 'y': 
             b = 'Dividend Yield'
        elif a == 'b':
             b = 'Bid'
        elif a == 'd':
             b = 'Dividend per Share'
        elif a == 'b2':
             b = 'Ask (Realtime)'
        elif a == 'r1':
             b = 'Dividend Pay Date'
        elif a == 'b3':
             b = 'Bid (Realtime)'
        elif a == 'q':
             b = 'Ex-Dividend Date'
        elif a == 'p':
             b = 'Previous Close'
        elif a == 'o':
             b = 'Open'
        elif a == 'c1':
             b = 'Change'
        elif a == 'd1':
             b = 'Last Trade Date'
        elif a == 'c':
             b = 'Change & Percent Change'
        elif a == 'd2':
             b = 'Trade Date'
        elif a == 'c6':
             b = 'Change (Realtime)'
        elif a == 't1':
             b = 'Last Trade Time'
        elif a == 'k2':
             b = 'Change Percent (Realtime)'
        elif a == 'p2':
             b = 'Change in Percent'    
        elif a == 'c8':
             b = 'After Hours Change (Realtime)'
        elif a == 'm5':
             b = 'Change From 200 Day Moving Average'
        elif a == 'c3':
             b = 'Commission'
        elif a == 'm6':
             b = 'Percent Change From 200 Day Moving Average'
        elif a == 'g':
             b = 'Days Low'
        elif a == 'm7':
             b = 'Change From 50 Day Moving Average'
        elif a == 'h':
             b = 'Days High'
        elif a == 'm8':
             b = 'Percent Change From 50 Day Moving Average'
        elif a == 'k1':
             b = 'Last Trade (Realtime) With Time'
        elif a == 'm3':
             b = '50 Day Moving Average'
        elif a == 'l':
             b = 'Last Trade (With Time)'
        elif a == 'm4':
             b = '200 Day Moving Average'
        elif a == 'l1':
             b = 'Last Trade (Price Only)'
        elif a == 't8':
             b = '1 yr Target Price'    
        elif a == 'w1': 
             b = 'Days Value Change'
        elif a == 'g1':
             b = 'Holdings Gain Percent'
        elif a == 'w4':
             b = 'Days Value Change (Realtime)'
        elif a == 'g3':
             b = 'Annualized Gain'
        elif a == 'p1':
             b = 'Price Paid'
        elif a == 'g4':
             b = 'Holdings Gain'
        elif a == 'm':
             b = 'Days Range'
        elif a == 'g5':
             b = 'Holdings Gain Percent (Realtime)'
        elif a == 'm2':
             b = 'Days Range (Realtime)'
        elif a == 'g6':
             b = 'Holdings Gain (Realtime)'
        elif a == 'k':
             b = '52 Week High'
        elif a == 'v':
             b = 'More Info'
        elif a == 'j':
             b = '52 week Low'
        elif a == 'j1':
             b = 'Market Capitalization'
        elif a == 'j5':
             b = 'Change From 52 Week Low'
        elif a == 'j3':
             b = 'Market Cap (Realtime)'
        elif a == 'k4':
             b = 'Change From 52 week High'
        elif a == 'f6':
             b = 'Float Shares'
        elif a == 'j6':
             b = 'Percent Change From 52 week Low'
        elif a == 'n':
             b ='Name'
        elif a == 'k5':
             b = 'Percent Change From 52 week High'
        elif a == 'n4':
             b = 'Notes'
        elif a == 'w':
             b = '52 week Range'
        elif a == 's':
             b = 'Symbol'
        elif a == 's1':
             b = 'Shares Owned'
        elif a == 'x':
             b = 'Stock Exchange'
        elif a == 'j2':
             b = 'Shares Outstanding' 
        elif a == 'v':
             b = 'Volume'
        elif a == 'a5':
             b = 'Ask Size'
        elif a == 'b6':
             b = 'Bid Size'
        elif a == 'k3':
             b = 'Last Trade Size'
        elif a == 't7':
             b = 'Ticker Trend'
        elif a == 'a2':
             b = 'Average Daily Volume'
        elif a == 't6':
             b = 'Trade Links'
        elif a == 'i5':
             b = 'Order Book (Realtime)'
        elif a == 'l2':
             b = 'High Limit'
        elif a == 'e':
             b = 'Earnings per Share'
        elif a == 'l3':
             b = 'Low Limit'
        elif a == 'e7':
             b = 'EPS Estimate Current Year'
        elif a == 'v1':
             b = 'Holdings Value'
        elif a == 'e8':
             b = 'EPS Estimate Next Year'
        elif a == 'v7':
             b = 'Holdings Value (Realtime)'
        elif a == 'e9':
             b = 'EPS Estimate Next Quarter'
        elif a == 's6':
             b = 'Revenue'
        elif a == 'b4':
             b = 'Book Value'
        elif a == 'j4':
             b = 'EBITDA'
        elif a == 'p5':
             b = 'Price-Sales'
        elif a == 'p6':
             b = 'Price-Book'
        elif a == 'r':
             b = 'P-E Ratio'
        elif a == 'r2':
             b = 'P-E Ratio (Realtime)'
        elif a == 'r5':
             b = 'PEG Ratio'
        elif a == 'r6':
             b = 'Price - EPS Estimate Current Year'
        elif a == 'r7':
             b = 'Price - EPS Estimate Next Year'
        elif a == 's7':
             b = 'Short Ratio'



        print('b =', b)
        print('c =', c)
        filename = "%s" % (b)
        filepath = "C:\\Python33\\Stock Data\\" + str(filename) + ".txt"
        print(filepath)
        print("future.result = ", future.result())

        try:
            data = future.result() 
            d = open(filepath,"wb")
            d.write(data)
            d.close


            # do json processing here

        except Exception as exc:
           for e in range(1,11):
                if len(data) > 0:
                    print('Byte length = %d' % (len(data)))
                    print(e)
                    print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (url, exc))
                    print('retrying %r' % (url))

                    def load_url(url, timeout):
                        conn = urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=timeout)
                        return conn.readall()
                        time.sleep(10)

                        print("press ENTER to exit")


        else:
            print('%r page is %d bytes' % (url, len(data)))
```

The various print statement shows the source text file contents being picked up correctly and passed through to the code ok. The line `print("future result =", future.result())` shows the following result:

```
b'31.90\r\n36.66\r\nN/A\r\n3.69\r\n25.52\r\n27.10\r\n525.33\r\n31.81\r\n56.90\r\n38.23\r\n23.86\r\n2.19\r\n66.93\r\n35.74\r\n21.74\r\n2.10\r\n26.08\r\n14.20\r\n26.73\r\n14.92\r\n48.42\r\n12.49\r\n19.31\r\n4.09\r\n3.37\r\n57.78\r\n45.85\r\n3.32\r\n60.02\r\n2.31\r\n18.50\r\n37.74\r\n3.42\r\n12.46\r\n14.03\r\n1.25\r\n15.13\r\n2.53\r\n1.73\r\n56.72\r\n44.98\r\n35.89\r\n1.05\r\n67.50\r\n17.35\r\n50.72\r\n20.72\r\n50.37\r\n6.27\r\n13.23\r\n77.50\r\n27.62\r\n24.49\r\n34.02\r\n24.56\r\n50.59\r\n25.50\r\n21.53\r\n31.33\r\n4.65\r\n4.65\r\n24.00\r\n52.04\r\n2.73\r\n24.78\r\n39.94\r\n20.57\r\n6.84\r\n2.97\r\n1.27\r\n24.08\r\n20.50\r\n7.44\r\n14.49\r\n13.22\r\n37.62\r\n4.39\r\n44.46\r\n44.46\r\n43.80\r\n22.58\r\n22.58\r\n48.92\r\n14.60\r\n50.12\r\n60.75\r\n2.36\r\n35.10\r\n8.47\r\n29.81\r\n53.13\r\n19.57\r\n12.95\r\n16.76\r\n59.70\r\n16.63\r\n4.74\r\n23.44\r\n37.52\r\n10.37\r\n52.81\r\n107.50\r\n6.64\r\n46.15\r\n15.50\r\n14.85\r\n72.06\r\n79.08\r\n14.25\r\n8.90\r\n1.91\r\n5.54\r\n35.43\r\n5.12\r\n177.09\r\n20.30\r\n20.60\r\n18.80\r\n28.30\r\n31.93\r\n31.93\r\n10.24\r\n1.65\r\n10.09\r\n1.83\r\n2.15\r\n74.23\r\n7.51\r\n14.38\r\n123.76\r\n12.89\r\n6.17\r\n23.22\r\n11.80\r\n19.70\r\n9.95\r\n17.93\r\n1.81\r\n4.18\r\n2.13\r\n42.81\r\n44.29\r\nN/A\r\n32.72\r\n373.95\r\n21.12\r\n1.85\r\n114.72\r\n20.25\r\n2.03\r\n16.89\r\n57.65\r\n13.28\r\n16.79\r\n42.24\r\n33.87\r\n77.08\r\n3.49\r\n7.26\r\nN/A\r\n33.95\r\n34.02\r\n32.33\r\n3.07\r\n2.42\r\n16.00\r\n2.87\r\n10.26\r\nN/A\r\nN/A\r\n13.45\r\n9.70\r\n17.36\r\n2.89\r\n14.61\r\n14.61\r\n29.00\r\n20.78\r\n11.39\r\n8.25\r\n71.81\r\n3.34\r\n22.15\r\n80.82\r\n47.80\r\n6.56\r\n26.67\r\n2.17\r\n28.43\r\n5.06\r\n48.16\r\nN/A\r\n6.00\r\n4.29\r\n20.20\r\n22.79\r\n17.75\r\n17.52\r\n17.52\r\n13.80\r\n'
```

This looks like the correct values to me, but just needing cleaning up. The destination text file resolves correctly and the all OK statement below the error handling returns the byte length of the URL submission correctly. The text file though remains empty.

Can anyone spot an obvious mistake I have made?

Thanks

Comment: Just a style note, you may want to replace that _awful_ ```if...elif``` block with a ```dict``` lookup instead

Comment: ... and it might be a good idea to populate that `dict` from a simple two-column CSV or KVP file, IMHO.

Comment: Yes you are right. I will move the long elif statement to a dictionary once I have it up and running.

Comment: Do you mean that all of the files are blank or only some are blank, or only the last one being created is blank?

Comment: My demo version had 86 hard coded URL statements of 1 stock x 1 metric. The current version will be 86 different URL submissions of 200 stocks x 1 metric. The data feed that yahoo provides is deliberately left dirty with inconsistent delimiting that it is impossible to code round so people subscribe to the paid feed. that is why i have to do it one ticker at a time. their URL submission rules also prevent more than 200 stocks at a time being submitted. in the hard coded draft the absence of the () at the end of the close file statement did not seem to prevent content from being output.

Comment: whereas in this version it did...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code

```
d.close
```

gives the result

```
>>> d.close
<built-in method close of file object at 0x0000000002C171E0>
```

Which is a variable description. In order to close the file you need to specify

```
d.close()
```

If the various values all apply to the same piece of data, then you would probably be better off building a csv file with the field headers in row 1 showing the header strings that you want then get the data and use a translation dictionary.

```
indict = {'a':'Ask', 'b':'y', 'd':'Dividend per Share', 'b2':'Ask (Realtime)'}
outname = indict[inval]
```

Output the csv file using csv.DictWriter() with the field headers that you choose using the appropriate parameters such as restval='' and extrasaction='ignore'

Now you can process the csv file and perform your analysis on all the data using only one input file rather than a separate input file for each piece of data.

Note: if you somehow open the same file twice, open it with 'ab' in order not to wipe out the previous data. It is a better idea to always open with 'ab' instead of 'wb' unless you specifically want to wipe out any previous data.

Comment: Using filepath = "C:\\Python33\\Stock Data\\" + str(filename) + ".txt" produces a file output with the correct name and without the code falling over. Spaces and dashes are permitted for the physical file names of text files. I've reverted back to my hard coded version of the script at checked the output. All 86 files are there. The issue in my current version of the code is not that the files arent created, it is that the content being captured is no longer writing to them.

Comment: user3043997 is the statement d.close a typo in your question or in your original program? It should be d.close()

Comment: no, it was in the original code and adding the () seems to have fixed it. in my original draft of the code the () wasn't in there either yet it still worked. any idea why?

Comment: @user3043997 I will add this to the answer and explain why it did not give a syntax error.

Comment: @user3043997 You can click on the check mark to show that this is the accepted answer and it worked (:-)

Answer (score 1):

Move `d = open(filepath,"wb")` and `d.close()` outside of the for loop.

Every iteration of the loop deletes and overwrites the file.
http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

EDIT:
I didn't see that the filepath is calculated in the forloop. I'd do what @sabbahillel pointed out, and open the file with "ab" mode to ensure it's not overwritten.

Comment: filepath is calculated from b within the loop and changes each pass through the loop so that the base path is changed by the addition of the string b.

Comment: patsweet - It is inside the for loop because this is a parallel processing piece of code. Eventually it won't be submitting just one statement at a tim e. Previously, using hard coded examples it worked fine where it was and produced multiple different output files with different content. I don't think it's position is the issue to be honest.

Comment: sabbahillel - previously when this was a hard coded variable in the Python script it worked fine, but now it is resolving from a string produced from a text file it is not, however the web submission itself seems to have worked.

Comment: Oh I see. Perhaps you should check if the file exists, and if it does, open it in "ab" mode to append data.

Comment: yeah the source file definitely exists and the target file is definitely created by the code as when i delete it reappears again after code submission but sans any content.

Comment: @user3043997 If you open it in 'ab' mode and it does not exist, it will open as if you had specified 'wb' mode and be created.

Comment: I dont think the issue is the structure of the code (i.e. things in the wrong place) as it has worked fine in hard coded versions. I think it is the contents of the string. In my hardcoded version only one stock metric at a time is called for one stock at a time. However in this example I am submitting multiple ones to yahoo!. the  string is now also coming from a text file source rather than just a hard coded piece of Python code.